# How to calculate hours that a clinic is open taking into account break times

Tags: mysql, sql, time, mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.3.

I am attempting to derive how many hours a clinic is actually open for a given weekday from an provider schedule table.

The clinic is considered "closed" if (1) all providers are at lunch or (2) no providers are scheduled to work at that time.

If at least one provider is still working while the others are at lunch, the clinic is considered "open".

Consider this clinic with four providers and a schedule from Monday to Wednesday.

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `provider_id` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `mon_beg` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `mon_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `mon_l_beg` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `mon_l_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `tue_beg` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `tue_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `tue_l_beg` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `tue_l_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `wed_beg` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `wed_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `wed_l_beg` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `wed_l_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`provider_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `schedule` VALUES ('Alex','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','12:00:00','17:00:00',NULL,NULL,'07:00:00','18:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00'),('Bob','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','08:00:00','17:00:00'
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/GvkvRKwaZ3Eeusj77CA4J/0

```
SELECT DayofTheWeek, (TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(clinicclose, clinicopen)) / (60 * 60)) HoursWorked
FROM (
SELECT 'Monday' DayOfTheWeek, MIN(mon_beg) clinicopen, MAX(mon_end) clinicclose FROM `schedule`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tuesday' DayOfTheWeek, MIN(tue_beg) clinicopen, MAX(tue_end) clinicclose FROM `schedule`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wednesday' DayOfTheWeek, MIN(wed_beg) clinicopen, MAX(wed_end) clinicclose FROM `schedule`
  ) calc


Expected Output:

DayOfTheWeek    HoursOpen
--------        ----------
Monday          8.5 (all providers take the same lunch)
Tuesday         9.5 (Alex is not scheduled for lunch, so the clinic is open)
Wednesday       11  (Bob and Charlie are still working while Alex is scheduled for lunch)
                    (Don should not affect the clinic's hours at all since he never comes in)

Actual Output:

Monday  9.5000
Tuesday 9.5000
Wednesday   11.0000
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I was going there, I wouldn't start from here. I think you need to seriously rethink your schema design. A database table is not a spreadsheet. :-(

Comment: Oh, this isn't my schema. It's part of a widely used clinic management system.

Comment: ...developed by a rival clinic

Comment: Is there some relationship between `provider_id` and employee?  I'm pretty confused on what you are asking.

Comment: They're synonymous. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedule;

CREATE TABLE schedule
(provider_id INT NOT NULL
,day CHAR(3) NOT NULL 
,day_start TIME NOT NULL
,day_end TIME NOT NULL
,lunch_start TIME NULL
,lunch_end TIME NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(provider_id,day)
);

INSERT INTO schedule VALUES 
(1,'Mon','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(1,'Tue','12:00:00','17:00:00',NULL,NULL),
(1,'Wed','07:00:00','18:00:00','11:00:00','12:00:00'),
(2,'Mon','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(2,'Tue','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(2,'Wed','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(3,'Mon','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(3,'Tue','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(3,'Wed','08:00:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(4,'Mon','07:30:00','16:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(4,'Tue','07:30:00','17:00:00','12:00:00','13:00:00');
```

Then, crudely...

```
SELECT day
     , TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(MAX(day_end),MIN(day_start))
              , TIMEDIFF(MIN(COALESCE(lunch_end,'12:00:00')),MAX(COALESCE(lunch_start,'12:00:00')))) delta
  FROM schedule 
 GROUP 
    BY day;

+-----+-----------------+
| day | delta           |
+-----+-----------------+
| Mon | 08:30:00.000000 |
| Tue | 09:30:00.000000 |
| Wed | 11:00:00.000000 |
+-----+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

extend your select

```
SELECT 'Monday' DayOfTheWeek, MIN(mon_beg) clinicopen, MAX(mon_end) clinicclose, , MIN(mon_l_beg) pausestart, MAX(mon_1_end) pausenend FROM `schedule`
```

for every day of the week
and then

```
SELECT DayofTheWeek, ((TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(clinicclose, clinicopen)) - (TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(IFNULL(pausenend,NOW()) , IFNULL(clinicopen,NOW()))) / (60 * 60)) HoursWorked
```

So you take the second of clinic open  and subtract seconds of the pause. If the paisestart is null it take the actual time

Answer (score 1):

For each day of the week, take the minimum of the lunch end time and subtract the maximum of the lunch begin time: if the result is less than or equal to 0, then the clinic is "open" during lunch; otherwise, the result is the time that the clinic is "closed" during lunch, and that number of hours should be subtracted from the HoursWorked that you already calculated.

Comment: What about for providers that have no break scheduled, cf. Alex on Tuesday?

Comment: You might have to replace all nulls with a dummy time, like noon. If every null value for the beginning and ending of lunch is the same dummy time, then the logic I described should still work.